# Google map api:geo location + custom markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how to add
1.geo location
2.load the marker name into a textbox on click
 my code http://pastebin.com/DUNgyfBD

Comment: Show us your code and what you have done till now.

Comment: Try adding some code, and explain your problem a bit more.

Comment: this is a map with multiple markers and what i need is 1.geo location 2.and when clicking on a marker , marker name should be loaded into a textbox<script src="//pastebin.com/embed_js/DUNgyfBD"></script>

Answer (score 0):

if this is on android studio then heres how you place a marker on the map, tinker on it for infowindow

```
 mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        try {
                //place marker where user just clicked
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
                LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                double latitude = latLng.latitude;
                double longitude = latLng.longitude;

                Geocoder geocoder;
                addresses = null;
                geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());


                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
   }
```